# How to add for loop inside jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, for-loop

i have array of data in mysql database, i want to display it one by one using for loop after getting the results using ajax. the process goes like this.

this is the paragraph where each items going to be rendered

when i try using for loop it says syntax error, unexpected for loop taken, how can i fix this
i.e. here i am using sample for loop in order to make things as easy as possible.

```
  $("#manager_paymentA").html(
    '<ul>'+
      for(let i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        '<li>Hello</li>'
      }
    
   + '</ ul>'  
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot loop inside the html function.
You should store the data into a variable:

```
var hello = ''
for(let i=0; i < 5; i++) {
  hello += '<li>Hello</li>'
}
$("#manager_paymentA").html('<ul>'+ hello + '</ ul>')
```

Comment: More specifically, you can't loop in the middle of string concatenation, but essentially the same thing.

Comment: A upvote for using the words I could not come up with. @freedomn-m

Comment: No problem, take a look at @tmsbrndz updated answer. That is an even better way

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) method.

Example :

```
 $("#manager_paymentA").append("<ul></ul>"); // Create the list

 for(let i=0; i < 5; i++) {
     $("#manager_paymentA > ul").append("<li>Hello</li>"); // Append elements
  }
```

Comment: You append it to the first ul on the page... The ul tag needs to be created first and only append to the created ul..

Comment: do you know what "example" means?

Comment: Yes I do, but this 'example' uses a tag name as selector. so will in most cases append to the wrong element . And if it appends to the right element, changing the pages html can cause problems.

Comment: After this edit: much better! changed to an upvote

Comment: After the edit, it will still not do the right thing if there is more than one ul in the `#manager_paymentA` element. If, for example, used in a function that is called mutliple times, this code will always add elements to every `<ul>`.

Why do you not just store the newly created element in a variable before you append it, and use the variable to address it later?

Comment: @JohannesH. true, but in most cases this wil work fine. If you make sure the #manager_paymentA has only one ul.

Comment: The difference between doing it this way and pre-building the string is that changes to the DOM have a *much* higher impact that string concatenation.   In this case, it's negligible, but needs to be considered; you should try to minimise DOM changes if possible.  This could also be easily made more efficient by caching `$("#manager_paymentA > ul")` (again, negligible in this case, but DOM queries also have an impact).

Answer (score 0):

You can not put the for loop inside the html function and add it between strings.
First build the string in a string variable, and than use that variable in the html function. example:

```
  var html = '<ul>';
    for(let i=0; i < 5; i++) {
            html += '<li>Hello</li>'
          }
    html += '</ ul>' ;
    $("#manager_paymentA").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of proving that creating a string with a loop in-line CAN (somewhat) be done in Javascript:

```
$("#manager_paymentA").html(
    '<ul>'+
        (() => {
            let s="";
            for(let i=0; i < 5; i++) {
                s += '<li>Hello</li>'
            }
            return s;
        })()
        + '</ ul>'  
  )
```

While this works, it's not really something I would recommend doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
//data is your array list
data.forEach(item=>
$('#manager_paymentA ul').append('<li>'+item.Name+'</li>');
)
```

You can access list items with the `item` element